# How can I set up my custom class to load a different class depending on the class option(s) passed?

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

I have written class files in the past. One of them is even up on CTAN. But that was ages ago, and I am rusty today.

I am trying to roll a new class file for my University. I am being a little ambitious, and want to use the same class file for University letters, forms, reports, etc (and use class options to select each type). The reason is that this is a LaTeX-resistant place and being able to provide just one file would help in selling the power of LaTeX to them. Plus, there is a coolness factor involved which I wish to explore.

Logically, each of those documents would correspond to inheriting from standard LaTeX classes and then adding local customizations.

Is it possible to have an option-dependent inheritance (`\LoadClass`) for a new class file? Or is that a fundamental impossibility?

Comment: Sure. Just define a macro to hold the selection and then pass the macro to `LoadClass`. e.g. `\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\myclasstype}}\LoadClass{\myclasstype}` where you have defined `\myclasstype` to hold the selection.

Comment: How about `\DeclareOption{option1}{\LoadClass{class1}}` instead?

Comment: That will work provided you don't want to pass any other options to the class. When I do this, I have a whole bunch of options and the class is only one of them. If your situation is simpler, you can do it more straightforwardly.

Comment: @cfr Maybe you could write an answer? :)

Comment: @MarioS.E. Sure. For what it is worth. It really depends on how the OP is handling options. But my answer should give the basic idea...

Answer (score 8):

I use something like this:

```
\ProvidesClass{superclass}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}% better option processing - there are many other possibilities as you probably know so just adapt as needed

\def\myclasstype{article}% make sure a default is defined

\DeclareOptionX{article}{%
    \gdef\myclasstype{article}}
\DeclareOptionX{report}{%
    \gdef\myclasstype{report}}
\DeclareOptionX{book}{%
    \gdef\myclasstype{book}}

%:pass unrecognised options off to \myclasstype
\DeclareOptionX*{%
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\myclasstype}}
%:process options
\ProcessOptionsX
%:load \myclasstype
\LoadClass{\myclasstype}% add options if desired
```

There are other ways to do this and I would not necessarily do it this way if starting from scratch as I think I could neaten things up using the facilities of `xkeyval`. However, it should be enough to give you the basic idea which you can adapt and streamline for whichever method of option handling you decide to use.

Comment: this is *so* good that I would like to upvote twice!